# AutoHotKey - LShift and RShift with arrow key, not working as I expected

Tags: autohotkey

```
>+Right::
    Send % GetKeyState("LShift", "p") ? "+{End}" : "{End}"
    return
```

code above is what I tried to implement (but failed).
However, code below, which was one of the tests, works... but not as smooth as I expected.

```
*Right::
    If (GetKeyState("RShift", "p") && GetKeyState("LShift", "p"))
        MsgBox Both Shift Keys
    Else
        MsgBox meh
    return
```

It has some delay, and sometimes does not show me anything. This is so weird.

It could be manufacturer's problem, but I wanted to make sure. Any elegant solution to implement first code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this simple thing is what you're looking for:

```
+<>+Right::End
>+Right::SendInput, {End}
```

It's using the simple [remapping syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remap) and your shift key gets passed through because the remapping syntax [internally uses {Blind}](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#actually).

And the second hotkey doesn't use the remapping syntax, instead just a normal send command, so the shift key will be consumed.

---

Another option since the first one didn't work on OP's end for some reason?

```
>+Right::
+<>+Right::SendInput, % (InStr(A_ThisHotkey, "+<") ? "+" : "") "{End}"
```

Since you had the cool ternary in there as well, I put it in as well. That code is the same as this:

```
>+Right::SendInput, {End}
+<>+Right::SendInput, +{End}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! I think I should search more about remapping. Unfortunately, your solution didn't worked. RShift and Right arrow didn't act as End nor LShift, RShift and Right arrow key didn't do anything. It might be my computer's problem. Could you give me more detailed explanation about "+<>+Right::End" so that I could get some hints from it?

Comment: Hmm, works just fine for me. What program are you trying it in? Try for example in just normal Notepad if you didn't already. Just to confirm, this is the desired behavior, correct? https://i.imgur.com/S7B8w3x.gif

Comment: `+<` is left shift and `>+` is right shift. Rest should be explained in the documentation links. If there's something more specific you're having trouble understanding, let me know and I can explain.

Comment: I'm using normal notepad too. I want to remap RShift+Right as pure End, and that means LShift+RShift+Right must act like Shift+End. Your solution is sadly not implementing the former one(pure End), and making it as Shift+End. LShift+RShift+Right is not dong anything again. Sorry if my English is too bad and thanks for your kind response.

Comment: Ok, edited the answer. Now I think it does what was requested.

Comment: Sadly LShift+RShift+Right is not working... https://i.imgur.com/Fn1YpPL.gif

Comment: Well that is odd. Lets try without the remapping syntax. I added in another option to the answer. If even that doesn't work, I don't know what to say. They all work for me. Any chance you'd have some other script which would be interfering?

Comment: OK, your current solutions all works (except few times)! I've figured out why your solutions didn't work. I should press those three keys with enough, slight delay. I don't know why, but anyhow it does. I think this is the limit and I should get used to those delays while using. Thanks for helping me out for a long time, wish you have a good day!!